# Using sed with an array

Tags: bash, sed

Could anyone tell me why this is not working?

```
Temp=$(sed -n '/"${Arr[$index]}"/,/"${Arr[$((index+1))]}"/p' $Text);
```

It still does not work. I tried to do this:

```
index=0
while [ "$index" -lt "$((Arr_LEN-1))" ]; do
    Temp=$(sed -n "/${Arr[$index]}/,/${Arr[$((index+1))]}/p" $Text);       
    let "index++"
done
```

Comment: What is the expected output, and what does it do instead?

Comment: Can you be more specific? How exactly "it doesn't work"? Error messages? How can we reproduce it?

Comment: i had 2 problems : first i used single quotes, second $text pointed to string and not file, thanks everyone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the `sed` script is in single quotes, which prevents all expansion:

> Enclosing  characters  in  single quotes preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes.

Changing single quotes to double quotes should help though:

> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \, and,  when  history  expansion  is
>          enabled,  !.  The characters $ and ` retain their special meaning within double quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are using single quotes.  Try:

```
Temp=$(sed -n "/${Arr[$index]}/,/${Arr[$((index+1))]}/p" $Text);
```